# using awk to display warning message from a specific file location

Tags: awk

I am trying to use awk to display a warning from a file if there is one and a "no error" message if there is a no warning.  The warning would be in field 2 and the first row is a header. Below is what I have tried.  Thank you :).

```
awk 'NR==1{next;} $2!=""{print $2}' C:/Users/cmccabe/Desktop/annovar/${id}_name.txt
```

Sample Data (from ${id}_name.txt)

```
Input   Errors and warnings AccNo   Genesymbol  Variant Reference Sequence Start Descr. Coding DNA Descr.   Protein Descr.  GeneSymbol Coding DNA Descr.    GeneSymbol Protein Descr.   Genomic Reference   Coding Reference    Protein Reference   Affected Transcripts    Affected Proteins   Restriction Sites Created   Restriction Sites Deleted
NM_004004.5:c.244G>A    (variantchecker): G not found at position 459, found A instead.
```

Sample Data 2

```
Input   Errors and warnings AccNo   Genesymbol  Variant Reference Sequence Start Descr. Coding DNA Descr.   Protein Descr.  GeneSymbol Coding DNA Descr.    GeneSymbol Protein Descr.   Genomic Reference   Coding Reference    Protein Reference   Affected Transcripts    Affected Proteins   Restriction Sites Created   Restriction Sites Deleted
NM_004004.5:c.79G>A     NM_004004.5 GJB2_v001   c.79G>A n.294G>A    c.79G>A p.(Val27Ile)    GJB2_v001:c.79G>A   GJB2_v001:p.(Val27Ile)      NM_004004.5 NP_003995.2 NM_004004.5(GJB2_v001):c.79G>A  NM_004004.5(GJB2_i001):p.(Val27Ile) BccI,BtsCI,FokI HpyCH4III
```

Comment: Without sample or representative data we will not be able to advise on what is or isn't working in your script. Please update the question with that if you want someone to really be able to help you.  In the meantime, right now your awk is assuming a space delimiter and has a syntax error by your `NR==1`.  I'm imagining you wanted to do `NR==1{next;}` to skip it.  Also, the `if($2 != ""){print $2}` should be just `$2!=""{print $2}`

Comment: I added some sample data to the post and will try the changes. Thank you :).

Comment: What is the field separator?

Comment: Still not clear what you like to do.  From the example data `$2` contains `Errors` in line one and  `(variantchecker):` in line two.  What do you like to test?

Comment: I also see now the (variantchecker): gets displayed, but I am trying to display that entire line but if that is blank then "no errors" displays.  The first line Errors is skipped, I modified the code and hopefully its better.  The field separator is a tab FS="/t"?  Thank you :).

Comment: Still far from clear.  Give example on various lines, with some you like and some you dont like and explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand exactly what you want to do.. Here is a script that skips the first line in the file (the header), parses every line after and looks for the second field in each line. If no error is found, it prints "No error".

```
awk 'NR>1 {e=$2; print "Found error: ", $2} END{if (!e) print "No error";}' <file_name.txt>
```

If you want to print the whole error message (everything in the second line except the first field), you can do something like:

```
awk 'NR>1 {$1=""; e=$2; print "Found error: ", $0} END{if (!e) print "No error";}' <file_name.txt>
```

Comment: This will print `Found error: ` for all lines except first line.

Comment: Isn't this what the OP requested? If I understood correctly, the error messages are from line 2 till the end (one per line).

Comment: I get `Found Error: NM_004004.5`.  I posted some more data that in excel  the second column has either (variantchecker): or is blank in it.  If it is blank then "no error" otherwise the (variantchecker):..... displays.... I hope this helps and thank you all :).

Comment: I think the second awk will work Radu... thank you :).