# using awk to parse a specific condition

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk`to parse multiple conditions and having some trouble with the first.  I think the code below is close, but it does not return the desired output.  The parse rules are:  Thank you :).

1. 4 zeros after the NC_  (not always the case) and the digits before the .
2. g. ###   g.###
3. c
4. t

   awk -F"[_.>]" 'FNR>1 {X=$4+0; sub(X, "", $4); print $2+0, X, X, $4, $5}' OFS="\t" ${id}_position.txt > ${id}_parse.txt

id_position.txt

```
Input Variant   Errors  Chromosomal Variant Coding Variant(s)
NM_004004.5:c.79G>A     NC_000013.10:g.20763642C>T  NM_004004.5:c.79G>A XM_005266354.1:c.79G>A  XM_005266355.1:c.79G>A  XM_005266356.1:c.79G>A
```

Desired output:

```
13     20763642     20763642     C     T
```

Comment: This looks very similar to your other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29038614/using-awk-to-display-warning-message-from-a-specific-file-location

Comment: It is, but I modified the script a bit and posted some data... I apologize if I did this incorrectly, but I though this might be easier to read.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk 'NR==2 {split($2,a,"[_.>]");b=substr(a[4],1,length(a[4]-1));print a[2]+0,b,b,substr(a[4],length(a[4])),a[5]}' OFS="\t" file
13      20763642        20763642        C       T
```